# Find and replace value best practice

Tags: javascript, lodash

- What is best practice for this?
- What is most performant?
- How can this be solved with the fewest characters? (without uglifying vars)

I’d like to use native or lodash. `inClass` may be unassigned, `Yes`, or `No`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < self.state.items.length; i++) {
  var obj = self.state.items[i];
  if (_.result(obj, 'student_id') === _.result(row, 'student_id')) {
    if (_.result(obj, 'inClass') === 'No') {
      self.state.items[i].inClass = 'Yes';
    } else {
      self.state.items[i].inClass = 'No';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"What is best practice for this?"* - For *what*? What is the problem you are trying to solve here? You mention using the fewest characters: replace the if/else with a ternary operator.

Comment: Is `inClass` `true` or `false` or `"Yes"` and `"No"`?

Comment: Why are you using the `_.result` method instead of using the dot notation?

Comment: Yes or No, you are correct

Answer (score 1):

Simplify using `forEach()`.

```
self.state.items.forEach(function(item){
   if (item.student_id === row.student_id) {
        item.inClass = item.inClass === 'No' ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    }
});
```

For me any minor performance difference is offset by cleaner looking code and is only really critical on huge datasets

Comment: It’s my understanding that `forEach` is much less performant than a standard `for` loop

Comment: @KirkStrobeck see my comments regarding that. OP asked for shortest code way then asked about performance...not sure which takes precedence

Comment: @KirkStrobeck performance wise I believe a `while` is even better than `for`

Comment: Practically of course, it makes no difference. `forEach` is better.

Answer (score 0):

This is a less verbose solution, the use of `._result()` seems like overkill:

```
var items = self.state.items,
    len = items.length,
    i, obj;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    obj = items[i];
    if (obj.student_id === row.student_id) {
        obj.inClass = obj.inClass === 'No' ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    }
}
```

In terms of "fewest characters", it's not really something you should be worrying about. The code should be readable as one of the highest concerns (in general).